# How to use multiple (or array) values in $content of shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, array, content

I have a shortcode that fetches some values, `first_name`, `last_name` and `email` from a remote database. I'm trying to write a shortcode that will allow me to print 2 or more of those values within output between shortcode tags. For example, I may call my shortcode like this:

```
[user_data]{{firist_name}} {{last_name}}'s email address is {{email}}[/user_data]
```

or maybe

```
[user_data]The email address is {{email}} belongs to {{firist_name}} {{last_name}}.[/user_data]
```

I know I can write a shortcode that prints 1 of the individual values and call it 3 times like this:

```
[user_data field="first_name"] [user_data field="last_name"]'s email address is [user_data field="email"]
```

But that seems rather inefficient to me. Suppose i have the shortcode:

```
function user_data($atts, $content=null) {
  $a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'uid' => 0
  ), $atts );

  // get an array with all of user's data
  $fetched_data = my_data_fetching_function($a['uid']);
  $out = $content;
  return $out;
}
```

Is there any way to make `$fetched_data` somehow available to $content?

Comment: the question can be phrased using pure generic PHP, no WP based solution is needed. It's just string manipulation. Loop through your fetched data, and for each key, do a search replace. You can do it using standard PHP string functions

Comment: I understand the concept of looping through and doing a search and replace, but I"m not quite sure where I need to do it. Something like `$content = str_replace('##' . $key . '##', $val, $content); return $content;`? or am i way off?

Comment: That's headed in the right direction yes

Comment: cool - i'll start writing some actual code and see how far i get. Thanks for the pointer